# How to upload mp3 & mp4 files to my ipod through iTune

Tags: itunes, ipod

Transfering music and videos to an iPod is so confusing after the latest updates.  It use to be simple as just drag and drop.  Now it is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer mp3 files:

Step 1. Connect your ipod to PC and launch iTunes.

Step 2. Go to the dropdown at top-left corner, select "Music"

step 3. Select "Songs" under "Library" from the left hand panel (if it is not there, use "edit" to bring it up.

step 4. Update your Library from this screen AKA drag mp3 files here.

step 5. Click iPod icon next to the dropdown list at top-left corner

step 6. Select "Music" on the left pannel

step 7. Check "Sync Music" and check all iTune catagories.  click "sync" button at bottom pannel

Transfer mp4 files:

Step 1. Connect your ipod to PC and launch iTunes.

Step 2. Go to the dropdown at top-left corner, select "Movies"

step 3. Select "Home Videos" under "Library" from the left hand panel (if it is not there, use "edit" to bring it up.

step 4. Update your Library from this screen AKA drag mp4 files here.

step 5. Click iPod icon next to the dropdown list at top-left corner

step 6. Select "Movies" on the left pannel

step 7. Check "Sync Movies" and click "sync" button at bottom pannel

now your mp4 files are in your iPod